# Count the occurrence of each element in large data stream

Tags: c++, hash, large-data-volumes

I have a simulation, with N particles, running over T timesteps. At each timestep, each particle calculates some data about itself and the other particles nearby (within radius), which is bitpacked into a c-string of 4-22 bytes long (depending on how many nearby particles there are). I call this a State String.

I need to count how many times each state string occurs, to form a histogram. I've tried using Google's Sparse Hash Map, but the memory overhead is crazy.

I've been running some reduced tests (attached) over 100,000 Timesteps, for 500 particles. This results in just over 18.2mil unique state strings out of 50mil possible state strings, which is consistent with the actual work that needs to be done.

It ends up using 323 MB in space for the char* and int for each unique entry as well as as the actual state string itself. However, task manager is reporting 870M used. This is 547M of overhead, or ~251.87 bits/entry, way over what Google advertises of about 4-5 bits.

So I figure I've got to be doing something wrong. But then I found this [site](http://incise.org/hash-table-benchmarks.html), which showed similar results, however, I'm not sure if his charts show just the hash table size, or include the size of the actual data as well. Additionally, his code does not free any strings being inserted into the hashmap that already exist (Meaning if his charts do include the size of the actual data, it is going to be over).

Here is some code showing the problem with the output:

```
#include <google/sparse_hash_map>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//String equality
struct eqstrc
{
    bool operator()(const char* s1, const char* s2) const
    {
        return (s1 == s2) || (s1 && s2 && !strcmp(s1,s2));
    }   
};

//Hashing function
template <class T>
class fnv1Hash
{
public:
    size_t operator()(const T& c) const {
            unsigned int hash = 2166136261;
            const unsigned char *key = (const unsigned char*)(c);
            size_t L = strlen((const char*)c);
            size_t i = 0;
            for(const unsigned char *s = key; i < L; ++s, ++i)
                hash = (16777619 * hash) ^ (*s);
            return (size_t)hash;
    }
};

//Function to form new string
char * new_string_from_integer(int num)
{
    int ndigits = num == 0 ? 1 : (int)log10((float)num) + 1;
    char * str = (char *)malloc(ndigits + 1);
    sprintf(str, "%d", num);
    return str;
}

typedef google::sparse_hash_map<const char*, int, fnv1Hash<const char*>, eqstrc> HashCharMap;


int main()
{
    HashCharMap hashMapChar;
    int N = 500;
    int T = 100000;
    
    //Fill hash table with strings
    for(int k = 0; k < T; ++k)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            char * newString = new_string_from_integer(i*k);
            std::pair<HashCharMap::iterator, bool> res =  hashMapChar.insert(HashCharMap::value_type(newString, HashCharMap::data_type()));
            (res.first)->second++;

            if(res.second == false) //If the string already in hash map, don't need this memory
                free(newString);
        }
    }

    //Count memory used by key 
    size_t dataCount = 0;
    for(HashCharMap::iterator hashCharItr = hashMapChar.begin(); hashCharItr != hashMapChar.end(); ++hashCharItr)
    {
        dataCount += sizeof(char*) + sizeof(unsigned int); //Size of data to store entries
        dataCount += (((strlen(hashCharItr->first) + 1) + 3) & ~0x03); //Size of entries, padded to 4 byte boundaries
    }
    printf("Hash Map Size: %lu\n", (unsigned long)hashMapChar.size());
    printf("Bytes written: %lu\n", (unsigned long)dataCount);

    system("pause");
}
```

### Output

```
Hash Map Size: 18218975
Bytes written: 339018772
Peak Working Set (Reported by TaskManager): 891,228 K
Overhead: 560,155 K, or 251.87 bits/entry
```

I've tried both Google Sparse Hash Map v1.10 and v2.0.2.

Am I doing something wrong in my use of the hash map. Or is there a better way to approach this, because with these strings, I'd be almost as well off just storing the list of strings, sorting, then counting consecutive entries.

Thanks for any help

## Edit

Because I was asked, here is format of the actual data:
Each component is 2 bytes, and broken up into two subparts. 12bits, and 4bits.

- First two bytes (short): [id of current particle (12 bits) | angle of
  current particle (4 bits)]
- Second short: [number of interacting
  particles (12 bits)(N) | previous angle of current particle (4 bits)]
- For next N shorts: [id of particle i (12 bits) | previous angle of particle i (4 bits)]

Angles are approximated (divided by 16), to store in 4 bits.

That's a bit wordy, so I'll write an example:

`0x120A 0x001B 0x136F` = Particle 288 (`0x120`), with angle 10 (`0xA`). Had angle 11 (`0xB`) in previous timestep. Interacts with 1 (`0x001`) other particle. This other particle is Particle 310 (`0x136`) and had angle 15 `(0xF`) in previous timestep.

Particles interact with between 0 to 9 other particles, hence the 4-22 bytes I mentioned above (although, rarely, can interact with up to 12 or more other particles. There is no limit. If all 500 particles are within the radius, then the string will be 1004 bytes long)

Additional information: The hashing function and compare function in my actual code use the size stored in the most significant 12 bits of the second short to do processing, since non-terminal 0x0000s can appear in my state strings. That all works fine.

Comment: It looks like your problem can be effectively solved by Map-Reduce-like systems... Yes, it's learning curve here, but this approach will scale reasonably well with growth of your data size

Comment: Ok, cool, I'll check them out. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Would you mind showing the real data - how the 4-22 byte state strings are composed?

Comment: Thanks for showing the data. - Efficient looking up of an element by the key isn't important here, and I think that you have answered your question yourself. 50 : 18.2 is approx. 2.7, so storing all state strings in full in 18 = 22-4 dynamic arrays shouldn't be all that expensive. Individual allocation of short chunks (4-22) will incur a significant overhead that can be avoided by the array solution (or by a specific malloc-like implementation).

Comment: Do you know what a Trie data structure (for storage of string lists) is?  If you have a lot of shared prefixes, it could save a massive amount of memory.  It also finds duplicates as a side-effect, storing the count shouldn't be difficult at all.  Just replace the "node-is-a-leaf" flag with a count.

Comment: @BenVoigt I thought about using a trie structure, but wouldn't the overhead be just as bad, if not worse, maintaining the trie? I guess I could do some tricks with arrays, but it would get complex.

Comment: @laune Yeah, I guess dynamic arrays will be best. And that overhead on malloc is crazy. It makes sense, just didn't expect it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These figures are from experiments with gcc on Linux. Allocating short chunks of 4-22 bytes requires 16 bytes for lengths from 1 - 12, 24 bytes for 13 - 20 and 32 bytes for the rest.

This means that your experiment with the 18218975 strings ("0".."50000000") requires 291503600 bytes on the heap, with the sum of their lengths (plus trailing 0) being 156681483.

Thus you have 135MB overhead simply due to malloc.

(Is this Peak Working Set size a *reliable* figure?)

Comment: Well, I just made a simple memory manager which has allocates 1MB char arrays as needed and uses that to write the strings for the hash map to. Down from 572MB overhead to 12.9MB. So seems the small malloc calls were chewing up 560MB or so of ram.

Thanks for the help.

As for the peak working set being a reliable figure. I assume so. It returned the same results (within 200K) every time I ran the program. I have also run the program on linux, and `top` and `ps ax` reported the same amount for RSS.